# Unit testing App engine - Eclipse - Maven

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit

For Appengine testing using Eclipse-Maven I have this defined in the POM.xml

```
    <!-- Appengine Testing -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

However, everytime I add this dependency, when my webapp is invoked, it throws this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocal
```

Although I can run JUnit and test my Appengine specific code, it is very painful that everytime I have to run the app I have to delete these dependencies and refresh everything.

Is there any workaround with this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the same POM as you (@xybrek), I solved this by doing a simple `mvn clean gae:run`, now it works from maven ...

Answer (score 0):

Which version do you use? My *POM* doesn't contain *appengine-api-labs*. Maybe you can try without it:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
  <version>${gae.version}</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
  <version>${gae.version}</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```